# What does a comma signify in inorganic chemistry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, notation, geochemistry

$\ce{(Ca{,}Co)CO3}$

I have never *ever* seen this before. What does this mean exactly?

Comment: It just means that relative amounts of calcium and cobalt are  indeterminate.

Comment: That's a *mixed* carbonate, similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_oxide

Answer (score 15):

Quoting [1]:

> **Comma.** In accord with general usage, the comma "," should be used to
>   indicate continuous substitution, partial as well as complete, if
>   there is no change of CN. Vacancies (symbol $\square$) are treated here just
>   like atoms. This usage is restricted to chemical formulas for atoms on
>   a specific site. The comma is not appropriate for structure site
>   formulas because different symbols indicate a change in the
>   coordination number. Examples for proper use of the comma include
>   forsterite-fayalite $\ce{[(Mg{,}Fe)2(SiO4)]}$ and hornblende $\ce{\{(Na{,}\square)Ca2(Mg{,}Fe{,}Al)_5[(Si{,}Al)4O11]2(OH)2\}}$. In structure type formulas, the
>   comma is used to mean "or" where substitution may occur. An example is
>   in the zeolites where H2O and M units may both occur.

Comma representation are often used in writing chemical compositions of minerals as the elements and its concentration vary to a certain extent. [See minerals.net:](https://www.minerals.net/resource/chemical_properties.aspx)

> **A number of minerals contain a varying amount of two or more elements like Aurichalcite, which has a chemical formula of
>   $\ce{(Zn{,}Cu)5(CO3)2(OH)6}$ contains an unspecific varying amount of
>   zinc (Zn) and copper (Cu). This is indicated by comma separating the
>   Zn from the Cu.** If a chemical formula with two elements in
>   parenthesis is separated by a comma, the number of those elements
>   vary. Aurichalcite has a variable amount of zinc of copper where the
>   combination of both these elements totals five. The more dominant
>   element is usually listed first. (Emphasis added.)

For more information, see [this previous Chemistry.SE question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33927/if-a-chemical-formula-for-a-mineral-contains-a-comma-are-there-limits-on-the-am) and [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472423/comma-in-chemical-formula) to find steps regarding how to write such type of formulae using chemical markups.

#### References:

1. Smith, D. K.; Roberts, A. C.; Bayliss, P.; Liebau, F. A systematic approach to general and structure-type formulas for minerals and other inorganic phases. *Am. Mineral.* **1998,** *83* (1-2), 126–132. [DOI: 10.2138/am-1998-1-212](https://doi.org/10.2138/am-1998-1-212). Online version: http://database.iem.ac.ru/mincryst/fst.html

Comment: When quoting, please make sure to quote correctly, or mark your edits within the quote.

Answer (score 13):

A short “obligatory” reference from *IUPAC Recommendations* [[1, p. 21](https://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf#page=33)], section IR-2.2.3.1 regarding use of parentheses in formulae:

> (d) In solid-state chemistry, to enclose symbols of atoms occupying the same type of site in a random fashion. The symbols themselves are separated by a comma, with no space.
>
> *Example:*
>
> 9. K(Br,Cl)

Related question on chemistry typesetting in $\mathrm\LaTeX$: [Comma in chemical formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472423/comma-in-chemical-formula).

#### References

1. IUPAC “Red Book” Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry, 1st ed.; Connelly, N. G., Damhus, T., Hartshorn, R. M., Hutton, A. T., Eds.; *IUPAC Recommendations; Royal Society of Chemistry: Cambridge, UK*, **2005**. ISBN 978-0-85404-438-2. [PDF](https://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this nomenclature used as a shorthand to indicate a solid solution of two different ionic compounds that share a common anion. For example:

1. Wang, Q.; Grau-Crespo, R.; de Leeuw, N. H. Mixing Thermodynamics of the Calcite-Structured (Mn,Ca)CO3Solid Solution: A Computer Simulation Study. *J. Phys. Chem. B* **2011,** *115* (47), 13854–13861. [DOI: 10.1021/jp200378q](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp200378q).
2. González-López, J.; Ruiz-Hernández, S. E.; Fernández-González, Á.; Jiménez, A.; de Leeuw, N. H.; Grau-Crespo, R. Cobalt incorporation in calcite: Thermochemistry of (Ca,Co)CO 3  solid solutions from density functional theory simulations. *Geochim. Cosmochim. Acta* **2014,** *142,* 205–216. [DOI: 10.1016/j.gca.2014.07.026](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gca.2014.07.026).

Since it's a solution of two different compounds, its composition can be variable.