# Parentheses use in non stoichiometric compounds

Tags: stoichiometry, notation

When should one use (or not) parentheses in writing the formula for non stoichiometric compounds.

I mean, the mineral sphalerite is often represented by the formula $\ce{(Zn,Fe)S}$ and, all though I know that this really means $\ce{Zn_xFe_{1-x}S}$, I would like to know when the use of the first formula is recommended over the second.

That said, I have done a brief search on the IUPAC's red book about the use of parentheses and found nothing.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [What does a comma signify in inorganic chemistry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119289)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule IR-2.2.3 / Parentheses, sub rule IR-2.2.3.1 / Use in formulae illustrates the use of parenthesis :

> (d) In solid-state chemistry, to enclose symbols of atoms occupying the same type of site in
> a random fashion. The symbols themselves are separated by a comma, with no space.
>
> Example:
> 9. $\ce{K(Br,Cl)}$

Note there is a subsequent, contrasting entry stating

> (f) To indicate the composition of a non-stoichiometric compound.
>
> Examples:
> 11. $\ce{Fe_{3x}Li_{4-x}Ti_{2(1-x)}O6}$ ($x = 0.35$)
>
> 12. $\ce{LaNi5H_x}$ ($0 < x < 66.7$)

source: p. 21 of IUPAC's Red Book by 2005 the [resources page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) (section nomenclature) links as freely available online release ([pdf](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Red_Book_2005.pdf)).

Comment: Certainly the example 11 is not one that could be denoted by parenthesis, since it does not represent atoms on the same site(s).

Comment: @JonCuster  My interpretation of the OP's question was as the notations of $\ce{(Zn,Fe)S}$ and $\ce{Zn_xFe_{1 - x}S}$ were mutual synonyms of and fully equivalent to each other. So far, I *speculate* this is not the case and hence included example f).

Comment: I indeed agree, just pointing out that parenthesis could _not_ be used for example 11. Coming from materials science, the implication of (Zn, Fe)S is you don't care what the ratio is, while for Zn$_{x}$Fe${1-x}$S you do care and there will be plots of something vs $x$.

Comment: (Zn,Fe)S and ZnxFe1−xS have different meanings, as stated by Jon Custer. In the 1st case Zn and Fe form a solid solution (Fe and Zn are located at the same crystallographic site). In the 2nd case, the formula implies a not-stoichiometric compound with Fe and Zn at different sites.  (Zn,Fe)S and (ZnxFe1−x)S are equivalent; in the 1st case, the relative amounts of Fe and Zn are not specified (even though the global amount corresponds to a stoichiometric coefficient equal to 1). In the 2nd case, you can specify the specific amounts of Fe and Zn by putting, for example, x=0.1, 0.25, and so on